# Conditional text with inline r code with the asis engine rmarkdown

Tags: r, r-markdown

I want to execute content conditionally via the asis engine as this tutorial points out:

https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/eng-asis.html

but I want to include inline r code but no matter what I do, it doesn't work:

````
```{asis, echo = mean(cars$speed)>1}
The mean of the cars speed is: mean(cars$speed)
```
````

I understand I can use this instead but I'm just wondering why I can't use the above code:

````
```{r conditional_block, eval=mean(cars$speed)>1,results='asis', echo=FALSE}
cat("There mean of the cars speed", mean(cars$speed)).
```
````

Answer (score 1):

The concept of conditionally including chunk output relies on the content being generated by a chunk. Inline R expressions use the notation:

```
Some text: `r expr`
```

You can not define chunk options for inline R expressions in RMarkdown, [more info here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/r-code.html). Even if you could define chunk options for inline R expressions, it would only suppress the `r expr` part, and the "Some text:" would still be printed no matter what.

Your second solution is great. It suppresses the text *and* the value when the condition is unmet.